# Identifying wait_resource for wait_info Extended Events

Tags: sql-server, extended-events, blocking

[image: wait_info]

Is there a way to identify what type/name of resource that is being waited on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *wait_resource* column of the *wait_info* XE is a pointer; I'm unaware of a way to decode this.

You might try instead to use the *wait_completed* event, which also has a *wait_resource* column that is more human-friendly. It's optional, though, so make sure it's enabled.

[image]

You can then use Kendra's article [Decoding Key and Page WaitResource for Deadlocks and Blocking](https://littlekendra.com/2016/10/17/decoding-key-and-page-waitresource-for-deadlocks-and-blocking/) to decode the resource.

In this case:

```sql
USE DbName /* Db with id = 5 */
SELECT 
    sc.name as schema_name, 
    so.name as object_name, 
    si.name as index_name
FROM sys.partitions AS p
JOIN sys.objects as so on 
    p.object_id=so.object_id
JOIN sys.indexes as si on 
    p.index_id=si.index_id and 
    p.object_id=si.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas AS sc on 
    so.schema_id=sc.schema_id
WHERE hobt_id = 72057594045923328;
GO
```

[image]